# Is it all right to put a large non-Python file into site-packages?

Tags: python

A product that I plan to develop will include both Python code and a zipfile (with a custom extension and custom contents, which do not include Python code). The Python code will go into the site-packages directory hierarchy. I know that it would be possible to write/generate custom code that knows where to locate the zipfile (possibly by reading a text file that contains a path), and then run this code when the Python code is imported. However, would it also be possible to put the zipfile into the site-packages directory hierarchy, which would be a somewhat simpler solution? From the reading I've done (David Beazley's "Python Essential Reference" and various web sites), I don't see anyone mention putting large non-Python files into site-packages, but I don't see anyone rule it out, either. My inclination is to avoid putting the file there, but I just wanted to see whether there's an outright reason for not doing it.

Comment: There are usually better places to put it, depending on the OS.

Comment: Usually stuff like templates or images would go in /usr/local/share/, but there's no real reason not to have them in site-packages. Anything that bundles non-python code that generates an egg file is. You might find some more traditional answers in the distutils code though, it has a concept of 'data' files and I believe may treat them differently.. if not, consider yourself in the clear.

Comment: Thanks for the distutils/data_files tip, @synthesizerpatel. I'm looking into it ( https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files ).

Comment: @synthesizerpatel agreed except for the "/" at the beginning in case the module gets installed in a virtualenv then it should create a usr/share or whatever from the virtualenv root and not in a hard coded path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it's fine to put such files not in site-packages itself, but in a directory, of any name you like, that is under the same hierarchy as site-packages. (You could call it a "cousin" directory, if not exactly a sibling.) As mentioned by @synthesizerpatel, distutils has a concept of data files. In fact, there is a keyword, "data_files", that can be used to indicate a directory of this type. For instance, you can write your setup.py file to contain a block like this:

```
setup(
    name="mypackage",
    version="R2014",
    description='My module',
    author='me',
    url='http://www.example.com/',
    platforms=['Linux', 'Windows', 'MacOS'],
    package_dir={'': 'dist'},
    packages=['my_package'],
    cmdclass={'build_py': BuildMyPackage},
    data_files=[('my_data', ['path/in/my/source/tree/to/some_large_file.txt'])]
)
```

In this case, executing:

```
python setup.py install
```

on a Windows machine will create a directory under the Python installation directory (e.g., c:\Python33\my_data) and place some_large_file.txt in it. Executing:

```
python setup.py install --user
```

will instead create the directory C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\my_data and put some_large_file.txt there.

Later, if you want to find the my_data directory, you can use distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib() or site.getsitepackages() to find the system site-packages directory, or site.getusersitepackages() to find the user site-packages directory. Then, since you know the relative path from there, you can find the directory that the setup.py script created. (Alternatively, you can use a relative path from site.getuserbase() rather than from site.getusersitepackages().) Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a simple, canonical way for determining in which of the possible directories (system or user) the setup was executed. Also, sometimes these functions give multiple possibilities, such as in this case:

```
>>> site.getsitepackages()
['c:\\Python33', 'c:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Thus, you may need to add a little bit of custom logic, such as:

- Search for the specified directory, using the known relative path,
  for all elements of site.getsitepackages()
- If not found, do the same
  for all elements of site.getusersitepackages()
- If not found, return "not found"